# Is there any way to load a single page at a time using Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

Blazor WebAssembly (WASM) allows the use of C# for front end development of web apps by compiling C# code into an app which is downloaded and run in the browser by WebAssembly.

The issue with this is that the whole app must be downloaded, which can take a long time and diminish user experience. Of course it's possible to reduced the app size to reduce download time via configuration and other means but is there a way of just loading an assembly for a page at a time as needed (or some other way of avoiding downloading the whole app at once)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the only current possible way (09/23) of not loading a whole Blazor application at once while using WASM, is to [lazy loading assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-lazy-load-assemblies?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

This is not really a good solution because application assemblies should be determined by the domain the code falls into not when you want it loaded in the browser.